# From JTable to Histogram - Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jfreechart

I have a JTable with three columns. For each rows I have a word, its type and the number of occurrences; for example in the next picture, the String "Rosing Prize" is present two times.

[image]

Starting from this JTable I want to build an histogram that takes as input the first and the last column. The first column is the name of bars and the last is its height; when the user selects some rows, they are represent in the histogram.

For example in this situation I have 4 rows selected:

[image]

The output are four J-Frames: the first with just one bar (that represents the first row); in the second J-Frame I have two bars (first and second row); in the third JFrame there are 3 bars for first, second and third row and, finally in the forth and last JFrame I have the correct output:
[image]

I thought about two possibilities to fix this problem:

1. to add a Jbutton and after one presses it the selected rows are drawn in the histogram
2. to add all JFrame to an ArrayList and to print only the last.

Are there better solutions?

Comment: Sure.  Add a JButton and draw the selected rows on a histogram on a JPanel.

Comment: Ok. This is not difficult. But is possible to paint histogram without JButton pressure?

Comment: Do you really want to draw a new histogram every time the user selects one or more JTable rows?   How do you tell when the user is finished selecting rows?

Comment: Yes I do. I need to draw a new histogram on a JPanel. I would like to implement something more dynamical of a Jbutton pressure, but if this is the only solution, ok. 
Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I added a `ListSelectionListener` listener to my table model.

In your [`ListSelectionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html), update the chart's dataset only when [`getValueIsAdjusting()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html#getValueIsAdjusting--) is `false`. This will defer updates until the selection is stable.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question right, `ListSelectionListener` will solve your problem.

Define a selection listener first:

```
class MySelectionListener implements ListSelectionListener {
```

Then add it to your table's selection model:

```
MySelectionListener selectionListener = new MySelectionListener();
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(selectionListener);
```

**Edit:**

Create a `MouseListener`. Then add it to your table. Here is a working sample code:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class TableTest {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();

    private TableTest() {
        createWindow();
    }

    public void createWindow() {
        Object rowData[][] = { { "Row1-Column1", "Row1-Column2", "Row1-Column3" },
                { "Row2-Column1", "Row2-Column2", "Row2-Column3" },
                { "Row3-Column1", "Row3-Column2", "Row3-Column3" } };
        Object columnNames[] = { "Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three" };
        JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);
        table.addMouseListener(new SelectionListener(table));

        window.add(table);
        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TableTest().createWindow();
    }
}

class SelectionListener extends MouseAdapter {
    JTable table;

    public SelectionListener(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        int[] rows = table.getSelectedRows();

        for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(rows[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, but this is not my problem. I added a `ListSelectionListener` listener to my table model. The problem is that if I have more than one rows selected, the listener is called for each selected row. (e.g. if 4 rows are selected my listener is called for one row selected, for two rows selected, for 3 rows selected and for 4 rows selected).

Comment: Did you try mouse listener? On `mouseReleased()` method you can get the selected rows and draw the chart.